# How to tint a button and then when you tap in it it doesn't change color?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I have a black icon that and I use it to image button. Programatically I tint this button gray. When the screen is displayed, the button is gray, but once I tap button, it turns black again.

This is how I tint the button:

```
addQuantityButton.imageView?.image = addQuantityButton.imageView?.image?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
addQuantityButton.imageView?.tintColor = .gray
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this and it will resolve your issue.

**Image Mode**

```
   addQuantityButton.setImage(addQuantityButton.currentImage!.withRenderingMode(UIImage.RenderingMode.alwaysTemplate), for: .normal)
    addQuantityButton.tintColor = .gray
```

**Background Image mode**

```
addQuantityButton.setImage(addQuantityButton.currentBackgroundImage!.withRenderingMode(UIImage.RenderingMode.alwaysTemplate), for: .normal)
    addQuantityButton.tintColor =.gray
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
setImage(image.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate), for: .highlighted)
```